# How to resolve data from an api using angular route resolver

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use angular route resolver to load an endpoint before it displays but I can not find a way to go about it
How do I pass the url of my API in my resolver as a parameter?
For some unique reason I need to pass in an parameter so I can not pass the api in the service.

This is my service

```
@Injectable()
export class HnService {  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTopPosts(endpoint) {
    return this.http.get(endpoint);
  }
}
```

This is my resolver file

```
@Injectable()
export class HnResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private hnService: HnService) {}

  resolve() {
    return this.hnService.getTopPosts(?);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to pass data and access to this data in your resolver you can use the data property when you define the path.

**First of all your route should be like this**

```
 {
    path: 'hn/:id',
    component: HnDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      response: HnResolver
    },
    data:{
      apiURL: 'my/api/url'
    }
}
```

**in the resolve**

```
@Injectable()
export class HnResolver implements Resolve<any> {
 constructor(private hnService: HnService) {
}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.hnService.getTopPosts(route.data['apiURL']);
  }
}
```

Comment: @arthur-decker see this one

Comment: I didn't use a snapshot though but your logic gave me more ideas thanks

Comment: Works on my end. Been searching for almost a day. I was referencing the ActivatedRoute data and getting a null value.

Answer (score 3):

**First of all your route should be like this**

```
 {
    path: 'hn/:id',
    component: HnDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      response: HnResolver
    },
}
```

**Your resolver should like this one**

```
@Injectable()
export class HnResolver implements Resolve<any> {
 constructor(private HnService: hnService) {
}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.hnService.getTopPosts(route.data['id']);
  }
}
```

***Note:***
*is asummed that your route is something like http://localhost:4200/hn/4*
where **4 is the ID of the hn** that u want to see the details

**in HnDetailsComponent details you can access to the hn resolved**

```
export class HnDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   const myHnResolved = this.route.snapshot.data.response;
   console.log(myHnResolved)
  }
}
```

I hope this help u to solve your trouble.

Comment: I am not passing in an ID I am passing in an API url

Comment: Please, check the new answer Arthur and let me know if u this solve your trouble